# RxJS - partition array of objects

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, partition, angular2-observables

How do I partition the following array so it's partition between those under 30, and those 30 and above.

I thought the following code would do it, but it appears to just return the array, not each element:

```
let ageArr = [
    { name: 'Ken', age: 28 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 70 },
    { name: 'Kate', age: 12 },
    { name: 'David', age: 37 },
    { name: 'Laura', age: 42 },
    { name: 'Ian', age: 19 },
    { name: 'Peter', age: 21 },
    { name: 'Isobel', age: 55 },
    { name: 'Rebecca', age: 15 }
];

let [under, over] = Oversable.of(ageArr).partition(person => person.age < 30);

under.subscribe(a => console.log(a)); // [ { name: 'Ken', age: 28 }, { name: 'Kate', age: 12 }, { name: 'Ian', age: 19 }, { name: 'Peter', age: 21 }, { name: 'Rebecca', age: 15 } ]
over.subscribe(a => console.log(a)); // [ { name: 'Mary', age: 70 }, { name: 'David', age: 37 }, { name: 'Laura', age: 42 }, { name: 'Isobel', age: 55 } ]
```

But as stated above, this seems not to work. Any idea how to achieve what I'd like to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Observable.from`

```js
let ageArr = [
    { name: 'Ken', age: 28 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 70 },
    { name: 'Kate', age: 12 },
    { name: 'David', age: 37 },
    { name: 'Laura', age: 42 },
    { name: 'Ian', age: 19 },
    { name: 'Peter', age: 21 },
    { name: 'Isobel', age: 55 },
    { name: 'Rebecca', age: 15 }
];

let [under, over] = Rx.Observable.from(ageArr).partition(person => person.age < 30);

under.subscribe(a => console.log("Under 30: " + a.name));
over.subscribe(a => console.log("Over 30: " + a.name));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You almost had it ;-)

Comment: Ha - very true... just one operator away. :) Thanks again!